# Regex match non-greedy with optional end

Tags: regex, regex-negation

```
TYPE1: Name Potential (parenthesis) (POSITION1)
TYPE2: Name (POSITION2)
TYPE3: Name with no Position
```

I am trying to extract 3 things. `TYPE`, `NAME`, `POSITION`. The position is optional. The name can have parenthesis.
I tried so many REGEX but can't figure out how to be non-greedy but to still include the parenthesis of the name.

These are supposed to be my final groups

- TYPE1, Name Potential (parenthesis), POSITION1
- TYPE2, Name, POSITION2
- TYPE3, Name

This one doesn't match correctly the first:
`(?<TYPE>.*?):\s*(?<NAME>[^(]*)\s*(?:\((?<POSITION>.*?)\))?`

This is too greedy, I don't extract the positions:
`(?<TYPE>.*?):\s*(?<NAME>.*)\s*(?:\((?<POSITION>.*?)\))?`

Comment: Wherer are you stuck? Please post your pattern and explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: Here you go... I have added it.

Comment: Is `type` always a single word only?

Comment: Yes. followed by :

Comment: Can `POSITION` also have parenthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with last group as an optional match:

```
^(?<TYPE>[^:]+):\h*(?<NAME>.+?)(?:\h+\((?<POSITION>[^)]+)\))?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zipw5q/5)

If `\h` (horizontal whitespace) is not supported in your regex flavor then use `[ \t]` instead.

Comment: This works well. Until I figured that NAME can be empty. I have updated a little bit my Regex but I based off yours! Thank you. `^(?<TYPE>[^:]+):[ \t]*(?<NAME>(?!\().*?)(?:[ \t]*\((?<POSITION>[^)]+)\))?`